# Is it inappropriate to ask for code reviews on github pull requests?

Tags: support, scope, code-ownership

I was wondering if there's a way to get code reviews on github. Although I think I know the answer to this question I want to double check.

There's a question open which is about asking a review of a full github repo. My question is more targeted to single small pull requests.

Thank you

Comment: Are you the author or maintainer of the project or PR and are you going to copy the code to Code Review?

Comment: I would be the author (I don't see why it wouldn't be the case). If the code is small I know I could copy it.

Comment: If you are the author and you will copy the PR to Code Review then you are fine.

Comment: I think my question is more like if I can add on top of my questions something like "The full PR is here (I would give the link) anyone who is willing to review the code in depth is welcome". I wonder if these kind of requests are inappropriate (i.e. my question would be closed).

Comment: Similar: [Is asking for code review on a patch file OK?](/q/144/75307)

Answer (score 3):

Code review requests must be *self-contained*, so merely pointing at the off-site material would be off-topic (as I'm sure you're already aware).

Assuming that you're the maintainer and/or author and you're willing to share using the CC-BY-SA licence, you could reasonably present a [comparative-review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comparative-review) question showing the original and modified code, provided it has *sufficient context* for reviewers to understand it without needing to consult the off-site repository.  So if it's only a part of your project's code, provide a good explanation of its purpose and how it gets invoked.

If you want to link to your code repo, that's fine as long as the question **doesn't depend on it**.  I recommend you link to the specific versions of the presented code, for the benefit of reviewers who want to obtain a copy of the exact code they are reviewing (they can generally navigate to the latest version from there).

Soliciting users to provide their review on another platform could be considered rude to this site, and I wouldn't want to encourage that, whether or not it's technically compliant with the rules.  But getting the review here, and incorporating it into your GitHub review process is fine (assuming you provide the proper acknowledgement required by the CC-BY-SA licence of the answers).